# jquery if checkbox value = 2 selected

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox

I want to make a judge, if `checkbox value = 2, selected.` But now my judge not work.

Jquery part

```
if($('#select input').attr('value')=='2'){
    $('#select input').attr('checked','checked');
}
```

Html part

```
<div id="select">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="1">item1</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="2">item2</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="3">item3</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="4">item4</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="5">item5</input>
</div>
```

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find out if checkbox with value `2` is checked then try this.

```
if($('#select input[value="2"]').prop('checked')){
      //
}
```

Since `checked` is a property of checkbox element it is recommended to use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
if($('#select input:checked').val()=='2'){
    $('#select input').attr('checked','checked');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.is` and `:checked` to see if the checkbox is selected. Something like below should do the trick,

```
if ($('#select input[value=2]').is(':checked')) {
 //do what if checked.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#select input").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';                     

    if(value == true) {
        alert('Checked');
    } else {
        alert('NOT Checked');
    }
});
```

See
[How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)